Проблемы с бэкапом на WP
При выполнении бэкапа сайта с помощью плагина UpdraftPlus, выскочила ошибка и еле смогла войти опять в админ-панель сайта. Если заходишь на сайт, то на главной странице целое полотно
Warning: mysqli_query(): Disk full waiting for someone to free some space... (errno: 28 "No space left on device") in /var/www/www-root/data/www/site.com/wp-includes/class-wpdb.php on line xxx.
Зашла в панель управления сайтом на хосте. Там нашла папку updraft. Все файлы, которые там находятся, совпадают по времени создания с моментом запуска бэкапа. Если удалить данные файлы, будет ли толк? Или решить можно каки-то другим способом?


Disk full waiting for someone to free some space...

Ошибка говорит, что на сервере закончилось место.
Нужно зайти по FTP или через ПУ хостинга и удалить ненужные файлы.
Для нормальной работы свободного объёма должно быть в 2 раза больше, чем занимает сайт.

Да, файлы уже удалила, все ок. Но каким образом в таком случае сделать бэкап? Только вручную? Вообще он мне нужен, чтобы можно было без проблем обновить версию WP с 6.3.4 до 6.5.3 и обновить еще и 21 плагин. Вряд ли без бэкапа стоит все это выполнять?

@SummerKnightHD04 ещё раз - Для нормальной работы свободного объёма должно быть в 2 раза больше, чем занимает сайт. И не важно каким образом делается бекап. Если столько места нет, то нужно увеличить. Единственное что - при обновлении можно не бекапить uploads, разные кеши и др. служебные каталоги плагинов. Соответственно рассчитывать место без них.
